# installed jenkins on windows ec2 instance

Tags: windows, jenkins, jdk

I have installed JDK 8 and Jenkins on Windows EC2 instance
I don't see any errors in the logs, but when I go to 
http://localhost:8080/ , I am getting a page cannot be displayed error

> Starting C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war"

Any ideas on what else I can check?

Comment: The log should include information about the service staring, including a line indicating that it is listening on port 8080. If you don't see any messages, you need to look in a different log.

Comment: Generally speaking, entering 'localhost:8080' in your browser will not get you to a server running on an EC2 instance. You need the internet address to reach the EC2 instance.

Comment: @Nate View this page  Amazon Web Services __Can't connect to EC2 instance via web browser__  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980017/cant-connect-to-ec2-instance-via-web-browser

Comment: Thank you, I have installed IIS Server and tried to browse to the default webpage and I get the same error "This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes."

Comment: Added firewall rule to open Port#80 for this server. Also checked that inbound traffic is open for 

All traffic   All  All  x.y.0.0/xx  and ip address falls in the CIDR block
 

 

 

  


Local Tenant Acces...

Comment: checked telnet your_ip 80 # Check http port and that is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed IE Enhanced Security to Off for Administrators to browse. In the long run, I will change the Group policy to fix it.